# How to obtain ideal color scale in corrplot?

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot, ggcorrplot

I have a matrix that I am trying to visualize using the corrplot package in R. The values in this matrix are fold changes of a treatment group relative to a control group (1 meaning there is no change, >1 meaning treatment group enhanced, <1 meaning treatment group reduced). Is there a way to utilize corrplot such that all values < 1 are on a red gradient, all values > 1 are on a green gradient, and all values = 1 are white?

Here is what I have tried:

Sample data:

```
testdata = matrix(rnorm(10, 1, 0.1), nrow = 5)
testdata
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 1.1368602 1.0123854
[2,] 0.9774229 1.0215942
[3,] 1.1516471 1.0379639
[4,] 0.8451247 0.9497677
[5,] 1.0584614 0.9666793

corrplot(testdata, is.corr = FALSE, col.lim = c(0, max(testdata)))
```

That produces the following:

[image: Produced Plot]

As you can see, there is no demarcation between values > 1 vs < 1. If anyone is able to share any way to set a transition point on the corrplot package that places all values > threshhold as being on one color gradient and all values < threshhold as being on another color gradient I would be extremely grateful! Thank you for your time.

**EDIT: Additionally, the values in the matrix range from 0 to >3 but I am still hoping to keep the 'white' transition point of the color legend of the corrplot at 1. If I use the suggestions from the helpful answers below it only works if the range of values in the matrix is between 0 and 2 which sets white transition point of color legend at value of 1. A range of 0 and 3, for example, sets the white transition point at 1.5 whereas I would like it to remain at 1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with `col` argument.

```r
library(corrplot)
#> corrplot 0.92 loaded

set.seed(123)
testdata = matrix(rnorm(10, 1, 0.1), nrow = 5)
corrplot(testdata, 
         is.corr = FALSE, 
         col.lim = c(min(testdata), max(testdata)),
         col = COL2("RdBu"),
         )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Edit**
You can manually control gradient range with `ggcorrplot`.
Note that `ggcorrplot` can be compatible with `ggplot2`, thus you can use `scale_fill_gradient2()`.

```r
library(ggcorrplot)
set.seed(1234)
testdata = matrix(runif(10, min=0, max=3),nrow=5)
ggcorrplot(testdata) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(limit = c(0,3), low = "red", high =  "blue", mid = "white", midpoint = 1)
#> Scale for fill is already present.
#> Adding another scale for fill, which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks YH! What about the case where the max values are above 2? For example if I do col.lim = c(0, 3), then the white color in the legend gets set to 1.5 whereas I would still like it at 1.

Comment: I edited the answer. how about `ggcorrplot`, instead of `corrplot`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware if you can use uneven divergent scales. But for an even divergent, with minimum as 0, like you stated and the scale centered on 1 you could do this:

```
corrplot(testdata, is.corr = FALSE, col = COL2('RdBu', 10), col.lim = c(0, 2))
```

[image: corrplot(testdata, is.corr = FALSE, col = COL2('RdBu', 10), col.lim = c(0, 2))]

Comment: Thanks Juan! Yes unfortunately I need to use uneven divergent scales as some of my values are above 2. When the matrix contains values above 2, the white color in the legend ends not corresponding to 1. For example a range of 0 to 3 sets the white color at 1.5 whereas I would still like it to stay at 1

Comment: I know this is possible in Python, but couldn't find anything useful in R sadly ):